# I'm trying to Write a Powershell script that will download all attachments, When i it Downloads the first 10 attachments only

Tags: powershell

```
    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxx" -AsPlainText -Force 
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com",$password 

$url = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages" 
$today = (Get-Date).AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

## Set date and query  
$messageQuery = "" + $url + "?`$select=Id&`$filter=HasAttachments eq true and DateTimeReceived lt " + $today
$messages = Invoke-RestMethod $messageQuery -Credential $cred

## Loop through each results 
foreach ($message in $messages.value) 
{ 
    # get attachments and save to file system 
    $query = $url + "/" + $message.Id + "/attachments"
    $attachments = Invoke-RestMethod $query -Credential $cred

    # in case of multiple attachments in email 
    foreach ($attachment in $attachments.value) 
    { 
        $attachment.Name 
        $path = "C:\path\" + $attachment.Name 

        $Content = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($attachment.ContentBytes) 
        Set-Content -Path $path -Value $Content -Encoding Byte 

    } 
}
```

When this is run only 10 attachments are downloaded then it stops.
I would like to figure out the reason why it stops at 10 so that i could go ahead and download an entire inbox.

Comment: First 10 attachments... of what?  The individual message?  The entire mailbox?  How many items are in `$messages`?  How many items are in `$attachments`?

Comment: that are in the mailbox it will cycle through all the messages in the mailbox but only download the first 10 attachments it run across.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue.  I think it only handles X amount at a time based on attachment size.  I delete mine out of the mailbox when I have successfully copied the attachment with these lines, since I do not need the email after I have harvested the attachments.

This (with the rest of my code) runs in Task Scheduler every 5 minutes, so if it doesn't catch all the mail in the first run, they will be processed, I guess 10 at a time in subsequent runs.

If ($DeleteEmail -eq "Y") {
    $query2 = $url + "/" + $message.Id
    Invoke-RestMethod $query2 -Credential $Credentials -Method Delete
}

Comment: In addition, it will not download any attachment over 10MB.  Now I am looking for a solution as well.